# iOS - In App Purchase items w/ metadata

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift3

Is it possible to store metadata w/ an IAP item(s)?

Example:

Let's say I have various cars available as IAP items.
Each IAP item has an image and a name. Can there be an arbitrary amount of metadata per item, such as: MPG, Color, Mileage, Number of Accidents,....etc?

Comment: On iTunesConnect, all the in app purchase has is a product code, a price tier and a description. In your app you can associate any other data you want with with that product code

Comment: What if I have an IAP that, when purchased, downloads a set of items (images + titles). In this case a single IAP item gives the customer a bunch of "things". Example would be if I purchase an item called "Monster Truck", then I will have available to be a bunch of different monster truck images (and their respective names).

Comment: You can store data anywhere you like and a purchase can be anything you like, but all the user actually purchases is a product code. Your app decides what happens when they purchase that code. The purchase doesn't even have to involve a download. It can just unlock content that is already in the app when you build it.

Comment: Yes, I understand an IAP can simply unlock features/content. In my case I would like an IAP to be downloaded (this is how I have set up things on iTunesConnect). Since I am working with downloadable content here, I was assuming there'd be some metadata associated w/ items that are downloaded.

Comment: The. Your download could be a zip file I guess and you can put whatever you want in the zip file, but there is no way to add arbitrary metadata into the SKProduct.